# Schwarzschild Solution, The constant of integration for 2+1 case

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

Lets say I want to find the spherical symmetric solution to EFE
$$G=2T$$
 in $d+1$ dimensions. The symmetries and EFE imply
$$ds^2=-f(r)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{f(r)}+r^2d\Omega^2$$
With $f(r)$ satisfying
$$f^\prime(r)\propto r^{1-d}$$
Therefore
$$f(r)=A\int^r\frac{dx}{x^{d-1}}$$
Comparison with the Newtonian limit, allows us to $call$ the constant of proportionality $A$ such that
$$\Delta f(r)=2\Delta\Phi_N$$
 One can easily check that changing the constant of integration is NOT a matter of coordinate (therefore gauge) transformation and different constants give rise to different worlds. A single choice may however be singled out by assuming flat ($f=1$) at spatial infinity.

Question: What about $d=2$? In this case the (different) answers are
$$f_a(r)=\frac{M}{\pi}\log(r/a)$$ 
None of which yields asymptotic flatness!

---

PS: My constants may differ from yours (Cf. My EFE) but that does not change anything. The problem is still there

Comment: Maybe a (2+1) world can not exist?

Comment: Maybe no mass monopole exists in 2+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity in 2+1 dimensions does not have propagating degrees of freedom, so vacuum Einstein field equations $Ric=0$ simply mean that the metric is locally flat. As a result, there is no Schwarzschild solution. Instead, a point particle corresponds to a conical singularity of a spatial slice of spacetime. Also, if one considers a negative cosmological constant (EFE then ensure that the spacetime is locally AdS₃), then there is a black hole solution, the [BTZ black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTZ_black_hole).

An overview of (2+1)-dimensional general relativity could be found here:

- Carlip, S. (1995). *Lectures in (2+ 1)-dimensional gravity*. [arXiv:gr-qc/9503024](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9503024).

Review of the BTZ black hole:

- Carlip, S. (1995). *The (2+1)-dimensional black hole*. Classical and Quantum Gravity, 12(12), 2853, [doi:10.1088/0264-9381/12/12/005](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/12/12/005), [arXiv:gr-qc/9506079](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9506079).